# Show filter attribute (size) in category listing page above product listings section

Tags: magento, filter, attributes, size, layered-navigation

I want to show size filter attributes near sort by drop-down section in category listing page,above product listing. By default its coming in left sidebar (layered navigation). Please provide me some solution which will show size filter attributes (Example: XL,L,XXL etc) in list page.

Answer (score 0):

change in catalog.xml of your theme

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

change reference name to "content" instead of "left" as per above then changes in css and template as per your need